# Apply CSS to a parent Table if child table TD doesn't contain value

Tags: jquery

I have a page containing a parent table and a nested table within it. 
*Sometimes* the nested table will contain the words "Signed" in a TD.

With JQuery, I'd like to achieve the following.

If a TD in the nested Table DOESNT contain the text "Signed", then give the PARENT table a text color of red.

Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector along with **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

```
$("table td:contains('Signed')").closest('table').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Hi Felix. I realised after trying your code that the solution was slightly different than my request. I need to color the parent table Red if the nested child table *does NOT* contain the word "signed".